# ajax pass javascript variable to php mailer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass a javascript array to php mailer via ajax, and can't seem to get it right. Email gets sent if I don't pass the variable, but doesn't get sent if I do. No errors are thrown.

Here's the ajax call:

```
function sendDetails() {
  var order = {
    name: "Foo",
    address: "123 Bar"
  };
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "getdata.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      order: order
    },
    dataType: "html"
  });

  request.done(function(msg) {
    $("#mybox").html(msg);
  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
  });
}
```

Here's getdata.php which gets variable and sends it out via php mailer:

```
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

if (isset($_GET['order']){
    $order=$_GET['order']; //works without this line
}
else 
    echo "not set";  //but no error message appears

file_put_contents("attachment.txt", $order);    

$address="recipient@email.com";
$mail= new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SetFrom("sender@email.com");
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
$mail->Username="sender@email.com";
$mail->Password="password";
$mail->SetFrom('sender@email.com');
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Dear Client");
$mail->Subject="Your details";
$mail->MsgHTML("somemessage");
$mail->AddAttachment("attachment.txt");
$mail->Body="Attached please find your details";

//no message appears
if(!$mail->Send())
{
  echo "Message sending failed.";
}
else echo "Message sent.";
```

Why does it work without the variable being passed, but fail when it is?

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: And is there an attachment when the message is sent?

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it. At the start of getdata.php if I instead of (isset($_POST['order']) I put if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"), it works. For some reason isset is returning false. Anyway I worked around it. But to answer your questions, I'm using php 5.5.3 and yes, there is a blank attachment that gets sent if isset is omitted. Thanks!

Comment: well, you're sending a ``$_GET`` request

Comment: oh yeah, didn't catch that, thanks!